# Can anyone help with function overloading?

Tags: c++, overloading

I have been asked to do function overloading and i am really confused. I need to :

1. Accepting no parameters and setting all co-ordinates to 0.
2. Accepting all co ordinates as arguments and setting data members to arguments.
3. Accepting an existing object of the same time as an argument, and duplicating the data members of this object into the current object.
4. Accepting an object of a point of lesser dimensionality, and copying only those data members that are able to be represented in the current object setting unrepresented dimensions to 0.

This is my code so far and i was wondering if i have done any of the above , if not can some one direct me how to do the others. Thank you

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;
//////////////////////////////
////// Class definition //////
//////////////////////////////

class point1DClass
{
private:
    int x;

public:
    point1DClass(); // constructor function
    int getx(); //Accessor function
    void setx(int newx); // Mutator function
    ~point1DClass();    //Destructor function
};
/////////////////////////////////////
//// Member function implementation//
/////////////////////////////////////
point1DClass::point1DClass()
{
    x=0;
}

void point1DClass::setx(int newx)
{
    x = newx;
}

int point1DClass::getx()
{
    return x;
}

point1DClass::~point1DClass()
{
    cout << "Object Going Out of Scope!" << endl;
}

class point2DClass:public point1DClass
{
private:
    int y;

public:
    point2DClass(); // constructor

    void sety(int newy); // Mutator function
    int gety(); //Accessor function

    ~point2DClass();

//isincident
//cityblock
//pythagDistance

};
/////////////////////////////////////
//// Member function implementation///
/////////////////////////////////////
point2DClass::point2DClass()
{
    y=0;
}

void point2DClass::sety(int newy)
{
    y = newy;
}

int point2DClass::gety()
{
    return y;
}

point2DClass::~point2DClass()
{
    cout << "Object Going Out of Scope!" << endl;
}

class point3DClass:public point2DClass
{
 private:
    int y;
    int z;

 public:
    point3DClass();

//    void sety(int newy);
    void setz(int newz); // Mutator function
//    int gety();
    int getz();

    ~point3DClass();
};
/////////////////////////////////////
//// Member function implementation///
/////////////////////////////////////
point3DClass::point3DClass()
{
//    y=0;
    z=0;
}

void point3DClass::setz(int newz)
{
    z=newz;
}

//void point3DClass::setz(int newy)
//{
//    y=newy;
//}

int point3DClass::getz()
{
    return z;
}

//int point3DClass::gety()
//{
//    return y;
//}

point3DClass::~point3DClass()
{
   cout << " Going Out of Scope!" << endl;
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////Main Function Implementation///////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////

int main()
{
    point1DClass x;// create an object

    x.setx(3);
    cout << "x co-ordinate: " << x.getx() <<"\n"<<endl;

    point2DClass y;
    y.sety(4);
    cout<<"y co-ordinate:" << y.gety() <<"\n"<<endl;

    point3DClass z;
    z.setz(8);
    cout <<"z co-ordinate:" << z.getz() <<"\n"<<endl;

  system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `This is my code so far and i was wondering if i have done any of the above` --> is it, or is it not your code?

Comment: Sorry it is my code, i missed out a word there it was meant to say i was wondering if i have done any of the above correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably going to want to overload the constructor.  So, for point3DClass, you'll want the following in the header file:

```
class Point3D {
    public:
        int x, y, j;
        Point3D(); // default
        Point3D(int i, int j, int k); // Make new point with (i,j,k)
        Point3D(Point3D copy);
        Point3D(Point2D copy);
        Point3D(Point1D copy) {
            x = copy.getX();
            y = 0;
            z = 0;
       }
}
```

If you reformat your code, someone will probably feel more generous :P

Comment: In the code you have written above where it says  Point3D(point3d copy) is this a copy constructor. Or is it just copying everything that is in the point3dclass?

Answer (score 0):

As this sounds like it should be [homework](/questions/tagged/homework), I'll try to provide enough clues for you to get to the answer.

**Inheritance**

When you create a subclass like `class point2DClass:public point1DClass {}`, any method that exists in point1DClass exists in point2DClass, e.g. getX()/setX() is available.

**Overloading**

Overloading allows you to do 2 things:

- Replace a parent method that takes the same arguments
- Supplement a parent method with one that takes different arguments

This means that if point1D has a method to copy values from another point1D instance, then point2D can copy from another point1D instance without any extra code (although Y won't be touched).

So, what about when we want to copy point2D into point2D? You could fetch the values from the 2D object, and store them, but this means increasing complexity as we build up to point 99D.

The solution is to call the parent method, then do any point2D specific work. As I want to leave some work for you, I'll demonstrate with some other code:

```
class A {
public:
    void copyFrom(A *a) { }
};

class B : public A {
public:
    void copyFrom(B *b) {
        A::copyFrom(b);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    B *b = new B();
    B *c = new B();
    b->copyFrom(c);
    return 0;
}
```

When the above code calls b->copyFrom, the implementation in B calls the implementation in A. Because class A doesn't understand class B, it treats it as the parent class A.

Hopefully this is clear enough to give you some hints.

***Note*** I know I've ignored *virtuals*, they're not in scope for this, and I don't want to write a C++ book

Comment: Hello, Is this a copy constructor. or within this code is it accepting coordinates as arguments and setting data members to match the arguments?

Comment: No, this isn't a copy constructor. Since #3 on the question said 'current object', I read that as a copy into an existing instance, rather than create a new instance based on existing data (which is what a copy constructor does). A copy constructor is just a constructor that takes an instance of an existing object as the parameter. The 'specialness' of a copy-constructor comes mostly from when it is used.